# Conditionally add registry key based on checkbox answer

Tags: windows, installation, inno-setup

I'm using Inno Setup for my Windows .NET app. I'm asking the user if they want to start the app with Windows with the following code:

```pascal
[Tasks]
Name: "TaskEntry"; Description: "Start with Windows?"; GroupDescription: "Startup";

[code]
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then                                          
  begin
    if WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[3] then
      MsgBox('Startup has been checked.', mbInformation, MB_OK)
    else
      MsgBox('Startup has not been checked.', mbInformation, MB_OK);
  end;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
    WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[3] := False;
end;
```

How do I add the registry key instead of the message box?

I'm aware that I can do it unconditionally with:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"; ValueType: string; \
    ValueName: "key"; ValueData: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any code for this. Add a [`Tasks`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentstasksparams) parameter to your registry entry and it will be processed only if this task is selected by the user:

```
[Registry]
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\  [...] Flags: uninsdeletevalue; Tasks: TaskEntry
```